# Wrong coordinates in R plot (package e1071)

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add single point to [`plot.tune`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-12/topics/plot.tune) but it ends up in a wrong place.
I'm calling

```
plot(radial.tune2, color.palette = topo.colors)
points(radial.tune2$best.parameters, pch=20, col='red')
```

where `radial.tune2` is `tune` object.
The parameters are as follows:

```
> radial.tune2$best.parameters
    cost   gamma
52 0.385 0.04125
```

[image: Point appearing to the right of where it should be]

I think this is due to the fact, that the scale bar is not taken into account (as I re-scaled the plot, the red dot appeared in different places relative to axes).

I looked into documentation, but found nothing about adding points to plots of `tune` object.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027730/how-to-plot-test-data-into-svm-plot-of-r-package-e1071) which seems to have similar origin, but does not address the problem properly.

**Edit**: here is simplified example of the same problem.
It produces different plot, but with the same shifting-to-the-right property.

```
library(mlbench)
library(e1071)

data(BreastCancer)
BreastCancer$Id <- NULL
BreastCancer <- na.omit(BreastCancer)
data <- as.data.frame(lapply(BreastCancer, as.numeric))
data$Class <- BreastCancer$Class
names(data) <- names(BreastCancer)

C.range <- seq(0.1, 0.7, by=0.05)
gamma.range <- seq(0.001, 0.30, by=0.05)

set.seed(1)
radial.tune <- tune(svm, train.x=data[,-10], # 10 -> Class
                    train.y=data[,"Class"],
                    kernel="radial",
                    ranges=list(cost=C.range, gamma=gamma.range),
                    tunecontrol=tune.control(sampling="bootstrap"))

plot(radial.tune, color.palette = topo.colors)
points(radial.tune$best.parameters, pch=20, col='red')
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Specify x and y separately in `points`.

Comment: @Roland it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is actually problem of `filled.countour` which is being called under the hood.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529212/plotting-a-box-within-filled-contour-plots-in-r) for more info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).